# Self-citation rewarded me 5 reputation

Tags: bug, documentation

Today I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712615/446594) citing myself from the documentation. I've noticed I was given [5 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee?tab=reputation) to do this.

Is this a bug or is this an intended feature, as I can see this could be exploited very easily ?

Comment: It looks like more possibilities for rep abuse in Documentation open up every day. That's quite sad. I'm afraid abusing the rep system in order to generate interest for Documentation may very well backfire in the short-to-mid term on the Q/A side.

Comment: Maybe it's a promotional campaign for the Documentation? With these free rep, you are really spoiling us SO

Comment: Promo or not, I don't feel someone should get this rep for just quoting yourself. Also why I brought this up to attention

Comment: You don't think someone should get rewarded for 1) taking the time to create documentation that helps people and 2) taking the time to find people for whom said documentation solves their problem? To me, that's exactly the kind of thing that should be rewarded!! If there are abuses of this system, it would be easy to systematically flag and deal with by diamond mods.

Comment: @corsiKa Sure, if that documentation has helped someone. In this case, the document had a score of zero... so, it's a little difficult to say, with confidence, that it's been helpful. You also seem to put more stock in this peer review than many of the people posting about docs on meta. I haven't had much experience with it myself, so the process may be every bit as rigorous and fruitful as you suggest. Time will tell.

Comment: @canon Then the peer review process needs to be fixed. Don't fault downstream operations for relying on an upstream process. Or maybe the citation rep is put on hold until the documentation is actually upvoted. I still think that's a minor problem compared to the grand scheme of things - OP thinks you shouldn't get any reputation for self citation at all which I think pushes people away from actively sharing knowledge, which is bad.

Comment: Maybe the citation rep should only be given when the answer that cites is upvoted....

Comment: I don’t see why *citing* docs should give any special reputation at all. Reusing content that was posted elsewhere already is less effort than writing a new answer, so I don’t see why it would be rewarded *with additional reputation* to do less while duplicating content into multiple locations. If the quotation makes the answer good, sure, then upvotes will award the answer. But *just because* it uses docs, does not make it good nor worth extra reward. If the question can be answered with a docs quotation, it should probably be closed as some kind of a duplicate instead.

Comment: @corsiKa creating good documentation should be rewarded somehow, and even if I don't think that it should get the same rep as SO, I can understand +5 for an upvote. Now, to give more rep because you simply linked to it is ridiculous. SO does not give rep to answers that link to actual documentation of the technology, why give it now?